# Oracle and MS-SQL-like row counts

Tags: oracle, performance, count, statistics

My applications often need an accurate but perhaps imperfect row count. Billion-row tables often get frequent writes, so "perfect" is a matter of definition and timing.

Microsoft SQL keeps very good metadata, allowing a query such as:

```
SELECT SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions
WHERE object_id = object_id('TABLE_NAME') 
AND index_id < 2;
```

(*There are other methods with different metadata*). This provides a nearly perfect row count, perhaps omitting certain in-progress transactions or other minutiae. Such techniques work for all but the most demanding situations and are practically instantaneous.

In Oracle, we *can* use statistics:

```
SELECT num_rows
FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

This is unreliable because, if statistics have been gathered at all, they are often out of date depending on DBA policy.

I can sacrifice significant accuracy for some improvement in speed using sampling:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 1000 rc_sampled FROM lot_size SAMPLE(.1) SEED(42)
```

However this is inaccurate by design, still quite slow (**115 seconds** on a 500M row test), and is almost useless when the application does not *already have* a row count estimate. Running that SQL on a table with 800 rows is like asking, "what is the price of that candy bar, give or take $75.00?")

Does Oracle provide a practical means of getting an accurate, *fast* row count for arbitrary tables, such as that which Microsoft SQL and others provides?

Comment: Oracle 12c(12.1 and higher) has `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT` which may do the job. (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions013.htm#SQLRF56900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Oracle database keeps track internally the number of rows affected by DML/DDL operations on a table since the last time statistics were gathered on it.

I have never used it for anything important, but you can give it try. First flush the monitored data from the memory to the underlying table, so you can query it (this also happens periodically):

```
exec dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info;
```

Then select the number of rows and adjust it with the inserts/deletes:

```
select
  t.num_rows - i.deletes + i.inserts 
from
  user_tables t 
  join user_tab_modifications i on t.table_name = i.table_name 
where
  t.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
;
```

Of course this is not 100 percent accurate, for example if the database was restarted just before an automatic flush, that information is lost.

But you should have up-to-date statistics on tables that change.

Comment: For future reference to others, my production query follows:
`SELECT tbl.num_rows + mods.inserts - mods.deletes rc
FROM all_tables tbl
JOIN all_tab_modifications mods
 ON tbl.table_name = mods.table_name AND mods.table_owner = tbl.owner
WHERE tbl.table_name = :tableName AND tbl.owner = :schemaName`

Answer (score 3):

> `SELECT COUNT(*) * 1000 rc_sampled FROM lot_size SAMPLE(.1) SEED(42)`
>
> *…still quite slow (115 seconds on a 500M row test)…*

You will find that `SAMPLE BLOCK` is a great deal faster because it does a tiny fraction of the IO that `SAMPLE` does. Of course if the data isn't evenly distributed it will cause the result to be less accurate, but this can be more than offset by increasing the sample size.

…but…

> In Oracle, we can use statistics…This is unreliable because, if statistics have been gathered at all, they are often out of date depending on DBA policy.

This is the real problem. Out of date stats cripple the CBO and are therefore "a bad thing". You likely need to change your DBA policy.

Comment: I used `SAMPLE BLOCK` in many tests but found that it would inexplicably return '0' much of the time. Any idea why?

Comment: Regarding statistics, there are absolutely reasons to not update in some cases, I have confidence that my DBA team knows their stuff. Old statistics are not a problem on most tables, but these are all in my experience beside the point. If I cannot consistently rely on statistics, on what alternative can I rely?

Comment: If your DBAs need plan stability, there are much better ways of achieving that than not updating stats. Re the zero sample count values, you may be hitting [this bug](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/sample-clause/) — try SAMPLE BLOCK (n,1). What's your version of Oracle?

Comment: Also have a play with various values on dbfiddle here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a8bce0c062a50558f9b59b79911f15a4 — I think the issue on 11g may be that the block sample is including empty blocks above the HWM and may randomly only include those for small samples (especially if the default sequential blocks scanned > 1)

Comment: We are using Oracle 8-12, mostly 11.
`Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production`
Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Comment: You are welcome. You might be interested in my follow-up question and answer on SAMPLE BLOCK here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166495/1396

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is accurate enough for you, but you could try using Oracle's built in [dynamic sampling](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/dynamic_sampling_and_its_impact_on_the_optimizer) functionality. Dynamic sampling is supposed to be used to get fast cardinality estimates when Oracle is creating an `EXPLAIN PLAN` but I see no reason why you couldn't use it as an approximate count if you parse the `EXPLAIN PLAN` text.

The number of blocks sampled depends on the level of dynamic sampling. For example, Level 1 samples 32 blocks, level 8 samples 1024 blocks, and level 10 samples the entire table. In theory, the higher the value you pick the more accurate of an estimate you will get, but you will need to read more data.

Let's try a simple example. Data prep:

```
CREATE TABLE X_TBL (DUMMY_DATA VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);

-- insert 500k rows
INSERT INTO X_TBL select 'ZZZZZZZZZZ' from dual connect by level <= 500000; 

COMMIT;
```

Next you need to create and store the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the dynamic sampling level of your choice. Here I use a level of 8:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select /*+ dynamic_sampling(X_TBL 8) */ * from X_TBL;
```

Now we can parse the text of the `EXPLAIN PLAN` however we want using [dbms_xplan.display](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xplan.htm#i999706). Here's one possible implementation:

```
select REPLACE(SUBSTR(plan_table_output, INSTR(plan_table_output, '|', -2, 1), 999), '|') AS CARD_ESTIMATE
from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'BASIC ROWS'))
WHERE plan_table_output LIKE '%SELECT STATEMENT%';
```

Unsurprisingly, in this case the result is exact: 500K

db fiddle link is [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f8e535af0cd34c4b859193081cf0f4e7).

I tested further with a sampling level of 5 against tables with 11 million rows and 63 million rows. The query took 4 seconds to run and was accurate to the nearest million rows. I can't figure out how to prevent the query from rounding to the nearest thousand or million, so if you need more accurate results this won't work.

Comment: Dynamic Sampling is also dependent upon what stats are in place.

Comment: @BobC what do you mean? Dynamic Sampling samples dynamically — it generates estimated cardinalities on the fly and the whole point is that it does not depend on pre-existing stats.

Comment: The amount or level of sampling does depend on what stats are available at the object level.

Comment: @BobC, can you clarify how that comes into play if I force a dynamic sampling with a hint?

Comment: @JoeObbish Yes you can force dynamic sampling with a hint. However in general, dynamic sampling should not be used as an "excuse" (for want of a better term) not to have object level stats.