# Why does SAMPLE BLOCK often return zero?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, count

In [a comment on another question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166377/oracle-and-ms-sql-like-row-counts/166380#comment321351_166380), someone asked:

> I used SAMPLE BLOCK in many tests but found that it would inexplicably return '0' much of the time. Any idea why?

I speculated that this might be to do with the sample hitting empty blocks but even if you tune the table to make sure all the extents allocated are completely full, [the behaviour doesn't change](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e8da2fe9b9c316007917cea3bbc79fe), so it can't be that.

test data:

> ```
> create table foo(bar integer primary key, baz char(1000));
> ```
>
> ```
> insert into foo(bar,baz) select level, 'A' from dual connect by level<=1000;
> ```
>
> ```
> begin
>   dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(null);
> end;
> ```
>
> ```
> select sum(blocks) blocks from user_extents where segment_name = 'FOO';
> ```
>
> ```
> | BLOCKS |
> | -----: |
> |    256 |
> ```

test SAMPLE BLOCK:

> ```
> with w(estimated_rows,distinct_blocks) as(
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50))
> select * from w;
> ```
>
> ```
> ESTIMATED_ROWS | DISTINCT_BLOCKS
> -------------: | --------------:
>              0 |               0
>              0 |               0
>           2000 |             143
>           2000 |             143
>           2000 |             143
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b3ae128c5604dc7548d728dae3fc7a0c)*

I found a Jonathan Lewis blog [on a related issue](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/sample-clause/) in 10.1, but this didn't explain why it is happening or how to work around the issue.

Comment: I think there's something off in the first db fiddle. This query gives a result of 5: SELECT count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo;  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3947ff864fce7951606a1bba7389c35

Comment: @JoeObbish that's worth of  another follow-up question I think :)

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be anything specific mentioned in the documentation, but [this Oracle Data Mining blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/datamining/entry/to_sample_or_not_to_sample_part_2) is interesting:

> SAMPLE relies on the existence of primary keys

I'm not sure this is true, but the existence of a primary key does play a role. The docs [do say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065953):

> Block sampling is possible only during full table scans or index fast full scans. If a more efficient execution path exists, then Oracle Database does not perform block sampling. If you want to guarantee block sampling for a particular table or index, then use the FULL or INDEX_FFS hint.

If you look at [the plan for the query you are using](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=922f6e6bb8501562734205fa7a771dd6), you can see it never touches the table, instead it is doing a fast full scan of the primary key:

> ```
> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                              |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 130955250                                                                     |
> |                                                                                                |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation                      | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |             |     1 |    45 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                |             |     1 |    45 |            |          | |
> | |   2 |   VIEW                         | VW_DAG_0    |   500 | 22500 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   3 |    HASH GROUP BY               |             |   500 |  6000 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   4 |     INDEX SAMPLE FAST FULL SCAN| SYS_C007394 |   500 |  6000 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> ```

The SAMPLE BLOCK is operating on the index — which [has far fewer blocks](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=930208a6853a77748fb20300f6231288) and is distorting the sample:

> ```
> select sum(blocks) blocks from user_extents where segment_name = 'PK_FOO';
> ```
>
> ```
> | BLOCKS |
> | -----: |
> |      8 |
> ```

With a primary key with more blocks the variability is much less, and you can alleviate the issue even more by using the second parameter in SAMPLE BLOCK to restrict contiguous blocks sampled to 1:

> ```
> create table foo(bar integer, baz char(1000), constraint pk_foo primary key (bar,baz));
> ```
>
> ```
> …
> ```

> ```
> select segment_name, sum(blocks) blocks
> from user_extents
> where segment_name like '%FOO'
> group by segment_name;
> ```
>
> ```
> SEGMENT_NAME | BLOCKS
> :----------- | -----:
> FOO          |    256
> PK_FOO       |    256
> ```

> ```
> with w(estimated_rows,distinct_blocks) as(
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50,1)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50,1)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50,1)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50,1)
>  union all
>  select count(*)*2, count(distinct substr(rowid,1,15)) from foo sample block (50,1))
> select * from w;
> ```
>
> ```
> ESTIMATED_ROWS | DISTINCT_BLOCKS
> -------------: | --------------:
>           1076 |              77
>            896 |              64
>            924 |              66
>           1006 |              72
>            810 |              58
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b01da74b58a40d3a2801107c911946da)*

This isn't a full explanation, and it might not be possible to have one without knowing how Oracle does the sample internally. What is clear is that whatever Oracle is sampling from, either table or index, [needs to be big to iron out the sampling wrinkles](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e549cddbb6bbe8bacc26c493a0d67467).

Answer (score 1):

Jack Douglas's answer is probably correct -- you need a large table for block sampling to be useful.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) rc FROM mytable
12894

SELECT COUNT(*) * 10 rc_sampled FROM mytable SAMPLE block(10) --repeatedly
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
128940
0
0
0
0
```

On a larger table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 10 rc_sampled FROM largertable SAMPLE block(10) --repeatedly
0
936300
498690
1354140
892250
2230010

SELECT COUNT(*) * 2 rc_sampled FROM largertable SAMPLE block(50) --repeatedly
724712
474462
347221
1066556
```

Sampling 99% is much better:

```
SELECT round(COUNT(*) * 1.01, 0)  rc_sampled FROM largertable SAMPLE BLOCK(99)
935917
937044
936088
932059
```

For large tables (>100M rows), block sampling 99% is it is still very slow (I stopped execution after 4 minutes).

Comment: "For large tables (>100M rows), block sampling 99% is it is still very slow" which makes perfect sense of course as you are scanning 99% of a lot of blocks. For very large tables you probably want to start with .000001 and keep going up by powers of 10 until you get something like a repeatable result.

Comment: Certainly, but when the numbers vary substantially even at 50% sampling, which should be about twice as fast as 99% (still slow for large tables), I wonder about the utility for arbitrary tables. I understand of course that not everyone has the "arbitrary tables" requirement.

Comment: It could be so much better, and I don't know why it isn't — but working with what we have, [using `sample block (x,1)`](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=afa7d1beb81902f069b5ec197494cafb) for tables in the 100M rows range probably makes most sense and `sample block (x)` for much bigger tables. YMMV of course as it is probably the number of blocks in the table rather than the number of rows that matters.